# Plot proportion from Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, kaggle

I am trying to plot proportion for age distribution for Titanic Data from Kaggle.

```
age_distribution_died= df.Age[df['Survived']==0].dropna().value_counts().sort_index()
age_distribution_survived=df.Age[df['Survived']==1].dropna().value_counts().sort_index()
```

What I would like to do is to group them in bins of size 10 , so for age 0-10, 10-20 etc. I tried with this code, however it didn't work:

```
bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
test = age_distribution.groupby(pd.cut(age_distribution,bins))
```

Comment: Can you show us output/traceback from executing your code? It makes it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\train.csv')

clean = df.dropna(subset=['Age'])

(clean.groupby(pd.cut(clean.Age, np.arange(0, 90, step=10)))
      .Survived.mean().mul(100)
      .to_frame('Survival rate')
      .plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.85, alpha=0.5, figsize=(14,10)))
```

[image]